# How to display a personalized icon for a custom menu in the admin side bar?

Tags: wordpress

I'm developing a plugin and I'm a little stuck trying to add a personalized icon to my custom menu in the admin bar.
I know the basic way to do this is to pass the address of an image file as one of the **add_menu_page** function parameters. I did that and it works, however, the icon is shown a bit "weird" compared to the standard WP admin icons. For example, the colors don't match even after I've edited the .png file a million times. This is specially true for when the mouse hovers the menu (the icon should turn blue, instead it goes white).
I've read some stuff about this, but nothing conclusive, and I can't find any official documentation about this problem.
BTW, I tried using an .svg, I think it's even worse!

So, I want to approach this in the most conventional way (I'm guessing there is one) so that I can display my icon properly even if the WP admin theme changes.
Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here's the code that adds my custom menu page to the admin side bar. It's pretty straightforward:

```
<?php

public function add_menu_pages() {
    add_menu_page(
        'My Page Title',
        'My Menu Title',
        'manage_options',
        'my-menu-slug',
        'render_my_menu_page',
        PLUGIN_DIR_URL . 'admin/img/my-menu-logo.png', // this is where I call my custom image.
        '26'
    );
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'add_menu_pages');
```

Comment: The WordPress dashboard uses Dashicons, if it was me I'd just pick one from the list of those so it's future proof regardless of theme. https://developer.wordpress.org/resource/dashicons/#pressthis

Comment: Thanks, @Andrew, but before posted this I already took a look at all the Dashicons and none of them really serve my purpose. Of course it would be by far the easiest choice, but unfortunately I need something very specific to represent my plugin. In the WP documentation they say that the best way to display an icon regardless of the color scheme is using a base64-encoded SVG, but I can't find a clear example.

Comment: This is what the WP documentation states about SVGs: __"Pass a base64-encoded SVG using a data URI, which will be colored to match the color scheme. This should begin with 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,'. "__ I just don't know exactly how to pair my SVG code with what they're talking about here. Maybe someone ran into the same problem as me, hopefully.

Comment: This question has already been addressed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30620226/custom-svg-admin-menu-icon-in-wordpress