# How do i convert multi path svg to one path

Tags: xml, svg, graphics

I have few images in .png. Using adobe illustrator I have converted them to .svg in black-white color mode.
In the generated svg file there are multiple path tags.

```html
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 22.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
      viewBox="0 0 512 512" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;" xml:space="preserve">
    <g>
     <g>
      <path style="fill:#FFFFFF;" d="M514,514c-170.7,0-341.3,0-512,0C2,343.4,2,172.7,2,2c170.7,0,341.3,0,512,0
       C514,172.7,514,343.4,514,514z M257.6,6.4C119.5,6.2,7,117.9,6.5,255.8C6,394.1,118.3,507.2,256.5,507.5
       c137.8,0.3,250.6-111.9,251.1-249.6C508.1,119.4,395.9,6.6,257.6,6.4z"/>
      <path d="M257.6,6.4c138.3,0.2,250.5,113.1,250,251.6c-0.5,137.7-113.3,249.9-251.1,249.6C118.3,507.2,6,394.1,6.5,255.8
       C7,117.9,119.5,6.2,257.6,6.4z M256.6,358.8c0.3,4.2,0.6,7.6,0.7,10.9c0.2,27.6,0.3,55.3,0.4,82.9c0,15.1-4.2,18.9-19.1,17.6
       C127,461,41.4,366.1,42.9,253.3C44.3,141.9,133.4,49.1,244.6,43c102.4-5.6,194.8,61.7,219.9,160.4
       C490,303.1,441.8,406,348.6,450.5c-3.7,1.8-7.8,2.9-11,5.4c-1.9,1.5-3.8,5.5-3.1,7.4c0.7,1.8,5,3.7,7.2,3.2
       c4.6-0.9,9-3.2,13.3-5.2C454,414,504.5,302,474.9,195.8C445.3,90,344.1,21.3,234.1,32.3C103.7,45.4,11.8,166.1,34.1,295.2
       C51.8,397.9,133.3,472.6,238.6,483c4.9,0.5,10,3.2,14.2,6c7.2,4.9,14.2,5.7,20.5-0.2c6.4-6,5.9-12.9,1.2-20.3
       c-2.5-4-4.7-9.1-4.8-13.7c-0.7-29.3-0.6-58.7-1.3-88c-0.2-8.2,2.4-12.5,10-16.3c25.9-13,39.5-40.1,35.9-68.8
       c-3.6-28-23.8-50.9-51.4-57.2c-6.9-1.6-14.2-1.8-21.3-2.5c-29.7-3.1-50.5-27.4-49.2-57.7c1.1-27.7,24.6-50.7,52.7-51.4
       c29.4-0.8,53.7,20.6,56.4,49.7c0.3,3.6,0.7,7.3,1.1,12c13.2,0,25.4-0.2,37.7,0c41.2,0.7,77.3,31.4,83.3,71
       c6.5,42.3-17,81.8-56.6,95.6c-6.2,2.2-11.4,3.7-17.4-2.5c-6.8-7-18.6-4.6-24.4,3.1c-5.7,7.5-4.6,17.8,2.5,24
       c7.1,6.1,17.1,5.2,24.3-0.9c4.9-4.1,10.5-8.1,16.5-10c40.8-13.1,69.4-51.2,69.7-93.9c0.3-42.2-27.1-81.6-67.6-94
       c-13.7-4.2-28.8-4.7-43.4-5.2c-9-0.3-12.6-2.4-14.9-11.7c-9.4-37.2-47.8-58.3-84.7-47.5c-36,10.6-56.6,49.1-45.4,85.3
       c8.9,29,32.5,45.8,67.7,48c23.5,1.5,42.5,16.3,49.3,38.3c6.8,21.9-0.6,45.7-18.8,59.6c-3,2.3-6.6,4-11.3,6.8
       c-0.3-5.7-0.6-9.4-0.8-13c-1.7-27.1-21.1-50.3-47.4-56.2c-7-1.5-14.3-1.4-21.3-2.6c-21.4-3.4-38.3-13.7-49.2-32.9
       c-3.2-5.7-3.7-10.4,1.4-16.5c3.4-4,4.5-12.6,2.5-17.5c-1.7-4.3-9.3-9-14-8.8c-5.3,0.2-10.6,5.4-15.3,9.2c-3.7,3-6,8.1-10,10.5
       c-27.5,16.8-43.1,48.1-38.5,78c6.4,40.8,37.8,68,79.4,68.2C189.1,359,222.2,358.8,256.6,358.8z"/>
      <path style="fill:#FFFFFF;" d="M256.6,358.8c-34.4,0-67.5,0.1-100.6,0c-41.5-0.2-73-27.4-79.4-68.2c-4.7-29.9,11-61.3,38.5-78
       c4-2.4,6.2-7.5,10-10.5c4.7-3.8,10.1-9,15.3-9.2c4.8-0.2,12.3,4.5,14,8.8c2,4.9,0.8,13.5-2.5,17.5c-5.1,6.1-4.7,10.7-1.4,16.5
       c10.8,19.2,27.8,29.5,49.2,32.9c7.1,1.1,14.4,1,21.3,2.6c26.3,5.9,45.7,29.1,47.4,56.2c0.2,3.7,0.4,7.3,0.8,13
       c4.7-2.8,8.2-4.4,11.3-6.8c18.2-13.9,25.6-37.7,18.8-59.6c-6.8-22-25.8-36.8-49.3-38.3c-35.2-2.3-58.8-19.1-67.7-48
       c-11.1-36.2,9.4-74.7,45.4-85.3c36.9-10.8,75.3,10.3,84.7,47.5c2.3,9.2,6,11.4,14.9,11.7c14.5,0.5,29.6,1,43.4,5.2
       c40.5,12.5,67.9,51.8,67.6,94c-0.3,42.7-28.9,80.8-69.7,93.9c-6,1.9-11.7,5.9-16.5,10c-7.2,6.1-17.2,7-24.3,0.9
       c-7.1-6.2-8.2-16.5-2.5-24c5.8-7.6,17.6-10.1,24.4-3.1c6,6.2,11.2,4.6,17.4,2.5c39.6-13.8,63.1-53.3,56.6-95.6
       c-6-39.6-42.1-70.4-83.3-71c-12.2-0.2-24.5,0-37.7,0c-0.4-4.7-0.8-8.4-1.1-12c-2.7-29.1-27-50.5-56.4-49.7
       c-28,0.8-51.5,23.7-52.7,51.4c-1.2,30.3,19.5,54.6,49.2,57.7c7.1,0.7,14.4,0.9,21.3,2.5c27.5,6.4,47.8,29.2,51.4,57.2
       c3.7,28.8-9.9,55.9-35.9,68.8c-7.6,3.8-10.2,8.1-10,16.3c0.7,29.3,0.6,58.7,1.3,88c0.1,4.6,2.3,9.7,4.8,13.7
       c4.7,7.4,5.2,14.3-1.2,20.3c-6.4,5.9-13.3,5.1-20.5,0.2c-4.2-2.8-9.3-5.5-14.2-6C133.3,472.6,51.8,397.9,34.1,295.2
       c-22.3-129.1,69.6-249.8,200-262.9c110.1-11,211.2,57.7,240.8,163.5C504.5,302,454,414,355.1,461.3c-4.3,2.1-8.7,4.3-13.3,5.2
       c-2.2,0.5-6.5-1.4-7.2-3.2c-0.7-1.9,1.1-5.9,3.1-7.4c3.1-2.5,7.3-3.6,11-5.4C441.8,406,490,303.1,464.6,203.4
       C439.4,104.7,347,37.4,244.6,43C133.4,49.1,44.3,141.9,42.9,253.3C41.4,366.1,127,461,238.5,470.3c14.9,1.2,19.1-2.6,19.1-17.6
       c-0.1-27.6-0.2-55.3-0.4-82.9C257.3,366.4,256.9,363,256.6,358.8z M198.8,345.6c0-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.3c16.4,0,32.7-0.1,49.1,0
       c6.8,0,9.7-2.7,9.4-9.9c-0.5-12.9-2.9-25-11.2-35.4c-11.1-13.8-25.9-18.9-43.1-19.7c-30.9-1.4-56.7-21.1-66.7-50.3
       c-3.2-9.1-6.6-10.4-15.2-5.4c-24.2,13.9-36.8,43.9-29.9,71.4c7,28.3,32.2,48.7,61.7,49.5C168.1,346,183.5,345.6,198.8,345.6z"/>
      <path d="M198.8,345.6c-15.3,0-30.7,0.3-46-0.1c-29.4-0.8-54.7-21.3-61.7-49.5c-6.8-27.5,5.8-57.5,29.9-71.4
       c8.6-4.9,12.1-3.7,15.2,5.4c10.1,29.1,35.8,48.8,66.7,50.3c17.2,0.8,32.1,5.9,43.1,19.7c8.3,10.4,10.8,22.5,11.2,35.4
       c0.3,7.1-2.6,9.9-9.4,9.9c-16.4-0.1-32.7,0-49.1,0C198.8,345.4,198.8,345.5,198.8,345.6z"/>
     </g>
    </g>
    </svg>
```

When I combine all these path by keeping content in d attribute i get image but it has only one fill color.

How do I convert these svg path to a single computed path with retaining original image in black and white fill.
I need single path to put it as an object in a custom js file where we are registering icons and using them with font-awsome-icon vue component.
The icons are registered by using varibales of format

```
var faSnd = {
    prefix: 'fac',
    iconName: 'snd-coin',
    icon: [512, 512, [], "E023", "M514,514c-170.7,0-341.3,0-512,0C2,343.4,2,172.7,2,2c170.7,0,341.3,0,512,0C514,172.7,514,343.4,514,514z M257.6,6.4C119.5,6.2,7,117.9,6.5,255.8C6,394.1,118.3,507.2,256.5,507.5c137.8,0.3,250.6-111.9,251.1-249.6C508.1,119.4,395.9,6.6,257.6,6.4zM257.6,6.4c138.3,0.2,250.5,113.1,250,251.6c-0.5,137.7-113.3,249.9-251.1,249.6C118.3,507.2,6,394.1,6.5,255.8C7,117.9,119.5,6.2,257.6,6.4z M256.6,358.8c0.3,4.2,0.6,7.6,0.7,10.9c0.2,27.6,0.3,55.3,0.4,82.9c0,15.1-4.2,18.9-19.1,17.6C127,461,41.4,366.1,42.9,253.3C44.3,141.9,133.4,49.1,244.6,43c102.4-5.6,194.8,61.7,219.9,160.4C490,303.1,441.8,406,348.6,450.5c-3.7,1.8-7.8,2.9-11,5.4c-1.9,1.5-3.8,5.5-3.1,7.4c0.7,1.8,5,3.7,7.2,3.2c4.6-0.9,9-3.2,13.3-5.2C454,414,504.5,302,474.9,195.8C445.3,90,344.1,21.3,234.1,32.3C103.7,45.4,11.8,166.1,34.1,295.2C51.8,397.9,133.3,472.6,238.6,483c4.9,0.5,10,3.2,14.2,6c7.2,4.9,14.2,5.7,20.5-0.2c6.4-6,5.9-12.9,1.2-20.3c-2.5-4-4.7-9.1-4.8-13.7c-0.7-29.3-0.6-58.7-1.3-88c-0.2-8.2,2.4-12.5,10-16.3c25.9-13,39.5-40.1,35.9-68.8c-3.6-28-23.8-50.9-51.4-57.2c-6.9-1.6-14.2-1.8-21.3-2.5c-29.7-3.1-50.5-27.4-49.2-57.7c1.1-27.7,24.6-50.7,52.7-51.4c29.4-0.8,53.7,20.6,56.4,49.7c0.3,3.6,0.7,7.3,1.1,12c13.2,0,25.4-0.2,37.7,0c41.2,0.7,77.3,31.4,83.3,71c6.5,42.3-17,81.8-56.6,95.6c-6.2,2.2-11.4,3.7-17.4-2.5c-6.8-7-18.6-4.6-24.4,3.1c-5.7,7.5-4.6,17.8,2.5,24c7.1,6.1,17.1,5.2,24.3-0.9c4.9-4.1,10.5-8.1,16.5-10c40.8-13.1,69.4-51.2,69.7-93.9c0.3-42.2-27.1-81.6-67.6-94c-13.7-4.2-28.8-4.7-43.4-5.2c-9-0.3-12.6-2.4-14.9-11.7c-9.4-37.2-47.8-58.3-84.7-47.5c-36,10.6-56.6,49.1-45.4,85.3c8.9,29,32.5,45.8,67.7,48c23.5,1.5,42.5,16.3,49.3,38.3c6.8,21.9-0.6,45.7-18.8,59.6c-3,2.3-6.6,4-11.3,6.8c-0.3-5.7-0.6-9.4-0.8-13c-1.7-27.1-21.1-50.3-47.4-56.2c-7-1.5-14.3-1.4-21.3-2.6c-21.4-3.4-38.3-13.7-49.2-32.9c-3.2-5.7-3.7-10.4,1.4-16.5c3.4-4,4.5-12.6,2.5-17.5c-1.7-4.3-9.3-9-14-8.8c-5.3,0.2-10.6,5.4-15.3,9.2c-3.7,3-6,8.1-10,10.5c-27.5,16.8-43.1,48.1-38.5,78c6.4,40.8,37.8,68,79.4,68.2C189.1,359,222.2,358.8,256.6,358.8z M256.6,358.8c-34.4,0-67.5,0.1-100.6,0c-41.5-0.2-73-27.4-79.4-68.2c-4.7-29.9,11-61.3,38.5-78c4-2.4,6.2-7.5,10-10.5c4.7-3.8,10.1-9,15.3-9.2c4.8-0.2,12.3,4.5,14,8.8c2,4.9,0.8,13.5-2.5,17.5c-5.1,6.1-4.7,10.7-1.4,16.5c10.8,19.2,27.8,29.5,49.2,32.9c7.1,1.1,14.4,1,21.3,2.6c26.3,5.9,45.7,29.1,47.4,56.2c0.2,3.7,0.4,7.3,0.8,13c4.7-2.8,8.2-4.4,11.3-6.8c18.2-13.9,25.6-37.7,18.8-59.6c-6.8-22-25.8-36.8-49.3-38.3c-35.2-2.3-58.8-19.1-67.7-48c-11.1-36.2,9.4-74.7,45.4-85.3c36.9-10.8,75.3,10.3,84.7,47.5c2.3,9.2,6,11.4,14.9,11.7c14.5,0.5,29.6,1,43.4,5.2c40.5,12.5,67.9,51.8,67.6,94c-0.3,42.7-28.9,80.8-69.7,93.9c-6,1.9-11.7,5.9-16.5,10c-7.2,6.1-17.2,7-24.3,0.9c-7.1-6.2-8.2-16.5-2.5-24c5.8-7.6,17.6-10.1,24.4-3.1c6,6.2,11.2,4.6,17.4,2.5c39.6-13.8,63.1-53.3,56.6-95.6c-6-39.6-42.1-70.4-83.3-71c-12.2-0.2-24.5,0-37.7,0c-0.4-4.7-0.8-8.4-1.1-12c-2.7-29.1-27-50.5-56.4-49.7c-28,0.8-51.5,23.7-52.7,51.4c-1.2,30.3,19.5,54.6,49.2,57.7c7.1,0.7,14.4,0.9,21.3,2.5c27.5,6.4,47.8,29.2,51.4,57.2c3.7,28.8-9.9,55.9-35.9,68.8c-7.6,3.8-10.2,8.1-10,16.3c0.7,29.3,0.6,58.7,1.3,88c0.1,4.6,2.3,9.7,4.8,13.7c4.7,7.4,5.2,14.3-1.2,20.3c-6.4,5.9-13.3,5.1-20.5,0.2c-4.2-2.8-9.3-5.5-14.2-6C133.3,472.6,51.8,397.9,34.1,295.2c-22.3-129.1,69.6-249.8,200-262.9c110.1-11,211.2,57.7,240.8,163.5C504.5,302,454,414,355.1,461.3c-4.3,2.1-8.7,4.3-13.3,5.2c-2.2,0.5-6.5-1.4-7.2-3.2c-0.7-1.9,1.1-5.9,3.1-7.4c3.1-2.5,7.3-3.6,11-5.4C441.8,406,490,303.1,464.6,203.4C439.4,104.7,347,37.4,244.6,43C133.4,49.1,44.3,141.9,42.9,253.3C41.4,366.1,127,461,238.5,470.3c14.9,1.2,19.1-2.6,19.1-17.6c-0.1-27.6-0.2-55.3-0.4-82.9C257.3,366.4,256.9,363,256.6,358.8z M198.8,345.6c0-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.3c16.4,0,32.7-0.1,49.1,0c6.8,0,9.7-2.7,9.4-9.9c-0.5-12.9-2.9-25-11.2-35.4c-11.1-13.8-25.9-18.9-43.1-19.7c-30.9-1.4-56.7-21.1-66.7-50.3c-3.2-9.1-6.6-10.4-15.2-5.4c-24.2,13.9-36.8,43.9-29.9,71.4c7,28.3,32.2,48.7,61.7,49.5C168.1,346,183.5,345.6,198.8,345.6z M198.8,345.6c-15.3,0-30.7,0.3-46-0.1c-29.4-0.8-54.7-21.3-61.7-49.5c-6.8-27.5,5.8-57.5,29.9-71.4c8.6-4.9,12.1-3.7,15.2,5.4c10.1,29.1,35.8,48.8,66.7,50.3c17.2,0.8,32.1,5.9,43.1,19.7c8.3,10.4,10.8,22.5,11.2,35.4c0.3,7.1-2.6,9.9-9.4,9.9c-16.4-0.1-32.7,0-49.1,0C198.8,345.4,198.8,345.5,198.8,345.6z"]
  };
```

Previous some svg i saw working fine had d attribute value with Capitals in it.

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0" y="0" width="512" height="512" viewBox="0, 0, 512, 512">
  <g id="Layer_1">
    <path d="M148.4,118.8 L148.4,118.8 L148.4,118.8 L148.4,118.8 L148.4,118.8 C148.856,122.528 148.656,120.661 149,124.4 C149.1,146.1 149.3,167.7 149.2,189.4 C149.2,191 147.3,193.2 145.7,194 C141.3,196.2 140.7,198.9 141.8,203.6 C149.5,236.2 162.4,266.8 176.7,296.9 C189.4,323.5 202.9,349.7 216,376 C216.9,377.8 217.7,379.5 218.7,381.7 C207.7,385.6 197,389.2 186.4,393 C180.1,395.2 173.8,397.4 167.7,400 C155.1,405.4 144.6,413 139.8,427.7 C135.1,418.6 131,410.5 126.9,402.4 C114.3,377.4 101.5,352.6 92.7,326 C83.5,298.3 84.6,271.3 95.8,244.2 C109.6,210.7 122.1,176.6 135.4,142.9 C138.1,136.1 141.8,129.7 145.1,123.2 C146.06,121.634 147.272,120.245 148.4,118.8 L148.4,118.8 z M376.3,90.7 L376.3,90.7 C371.6,102.9 362.3,110.2 350.9,114.9 C340.5,119.3 329.7,122.9 319.1,126.8 C312,129.3 304.8,131.7 297.2,134.4 C299.1,138.3 300.7,141.6 302.4,144.8 C321.5,182.1 341.1,219.2 356.5,258.3 C363.8,276.8 370.6,295.6 374.3,315.3 C374.9,318.4 374.5,320.6 371.5,321.8 C367.6,323.4 366.9,326.3 366.9,330.2 C367.1,350.9 367,371.5 367,392.2 C367,394 367.3,395.7 367.4,397.5 C368.1,397.8 368.8,398 369.5,398.1 C373.5,390.1 378.1,382.4 381.4,374.2 C394.1,342.2 405.8,309.8 418.9,278 C430.7,249.4 431.4,220.9 422.1,191.7 C410.9,156.6 393.8,124.2 377.7,91.4 C377.5,91.1 376.9,91 376.3,90.7 z" fill="#000000"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I am working with a project in vue and in this we are registering icons using objects and passing them to font-awsome-icon component.
For this syntax is like 
var x={
prefix:'fas',
iconName:''my-icon'
icon:[width,height,id,path]
}

the path here is one combined path we want.
This is basic requirement I have. I can explain my best to this only!

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: Just append all the path's d element contents separated by a space.

Comment: I did that but didn't get desired results.
Sharing two urls https://jsfiddle.net/ph5dtwmo/ and https://jsfiddle.net/rc47utb8/

The second fiddle output is completely black. I want to get second svg output same as first one.

Comment: The first path in your original drawing is a different colour. You can't combine paths of different colours into a single path. Your best bet is to start again and draw the path you want from scratch in an SVG editor such as inkscape.

Comment: Can you tell me the process to generate a single path from a .png file in Inkscape or adobe illustrator? I do not have any knowledge of this.

Comment: Just draw it from scratch.

Comment: Also relevant: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/71506/how-to-generate-a-single-path-for-a-svg-using-illustrator

Answer (score 17):

You can combine svg paths in [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/)  (open source svg editor) with [Path] [Combine]. This may force all paths to be the same colour.

If you have imported an image (eg bitmap) into Inkscape, first use [Path] [Trace bitmap] to create the paths, then you can combine.

Answer (score 8):

Here is your SVG with only one path. 
This is what I'we done: I've eliminated the white paths and I've joined the 2 black paths. See that gap in my code? Is where the first paths ended and the last one began.

The only problem now is that the formerly white path is now a transparent zone.  If you give your SVG a background you'll see it through the gap.

```css
svg{background:gold;width:90vh}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 512 512" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;" xml:space="preserve">

        <path d="M257.6,6.4c138.3,0.2,250.5,113.1,250,251.6c-0.5,137.7-113.3,249.9-251.1,249.6C118.3,507.2,6,394.1,6.5,255.8
            C7,117.9,119.5,6.2,257.6,6.4z M256.6,358.8c0.3,4.2,0.6,7.6,0.7,10.9c0.2,27.6,0.3,55.3,0.4,82.9c0,15.1-4.2,18.9-19.1,17.6
            C127,461,41.4,366.1,42.9,253.3C44.3,141.9,133.4,49.1,244.6,43c102.4-5.6,194.8,61.7,219.9,160.4
            C490,303.1,441.8,406,348.6,450.5c-3.7,1.8-7.8,2.9-11,5.4c-1.9,1.5-3.8,5.5-3.1,7.4c0.7,1.8,5,3.7,7.2,3.2
            c4.6-0.9,9-3.2,13.3-5.2C454,414,504.5,302,474.9,195.8C445.3,90,344.1,21.3,234.1,32.3C103.7,45.4,11.8,166.1,34.1,295.2
            C51.8,397.9,133.3,472.6,238.6,483c4.9,0.5,10,3.2,14.2,6c7.2,4.9,14.2,5.7,20.5-0.2c6.4-6,5.9-12.9,1.2-20.3
            c-2.5-4-4.7-9.1-4.8-13.7c-0.7-29.3-0.6-58.7-1.3-88c-0.2-8.2,2.4-12.5,10-16.3c25.9-13,39.5-40.1,35.9-68.8
            c-3.6-28-23.8-50.9-51.4-57.2c-6.9-1.6-14.2-1.8-21.3-2.5c-29.7-3.1-50.5-27.4-49.2-57.7c1.1-27.7,24.6-50.7,52.7-51.4
            c29.4-0.8,53.7,20.6,56.4,49.7c0.3,3.6,0.7,7.3,1.1,12c13.2,0,25.4-0.2,37.7,0c41.2,0.7,77.3,31.4,83.3,71
            c6.5,42.3-17,81.8-56.6,95.6c-6.2,2.2-11.4,3.7-17.4-2.5c-6.8-7-18.6-4.6-24.4,3.1c-5.7,7.5-4.6,17.8,2.5,24
            c7.1,6.1,17.1,5.2,24.3-0.9c4.9-4.1,10.5-8.1,16.5-10c40.8-13.1,69.4-51.2,69.7-93.9c0.3-42.2-27.1-81.6-67.6-94
            c-13.7-4.2-28.8-4.7-43.4-5.2c-9-0.3-12.6-2.4-14.9-11.7c-9.4-37.2-47.8-58.3-84.7-47.5c-36,10.6-56.6,49.1-45.4,85.3
            c8.9,29,32.5,45.8,67.7,48c23.5,1.5,42.5,16.3,49.3,38.3c6.8,21.9-0.6,45.7-18.8,59.6c-3,2.3-6.6,4-11.3,6.8
            c-0.3-5.7-0.6-9.4-0.8-13c-1.7-27.1-21.1-50.3-47.4-56.2c-7-1.5-14.3-1.4-21.3-2.6c-21.4-3.4-38.3-13.7-49.2-32.9
            c-3.2-5.7-3.7-10.4,1.4-16.5c3.4-4,4.5-12.6,2.5-17.5c-1.7-4.3-9.3-9-14-8.8c-5.3,0.2-10.6,5.4-15.3,9.2c-3.7,3-6,8.1-10,10.5
            c-27.5,16.8-43.1,48.1-38.5,78c6.4,40.8,37.8,68,79.4,68.2C189.1,359,222.2,358.8,256.6,358.8z
                 
                 
                 
                 M198.8,345.6c-15.3,0-30.7,0.3-46-0.1c-29.4-0.8-54.7-21.3-61.7-49.5c-6.8-27.5,5.8-57.5,29.9-71.4
            c8.6-4.9,12.1-3.7,15.2,5.4c10.1,29.1,35.8,48.8,66.7,50.3c17.2,0.8,32.1,5.9,43.1,19.7c8.3,10.4,10.8,22.5,11.2,35.4
            c0.3,7.1-2.6,9.9-9.4,9.9c-16.4-0.1-32.7,0-49.1,0C198.8,345.4,198.8,345.5,198.8,345.6z"/>
  

</svg>
```

Comment: This is a missprint width:90vh? Strange but works. The same scaling is obtained when `width:90vh` or `width:90vw`

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind using the language of Python, then see the below:

```py
from svgpathtools import svg2paths, wsvg  # you need ``pip install svgpathtools``
from svgpathtools.path import Path as CombinePath
from pathlib import Path


TEST_SVG = Path('test.svg')


def main():
    path_list, data_list = svg2paths(str(Path(TEST_SVG)))

    if not 'analysis path':
        for idx, cur_path in enumerate(path_list):
            wsvg(cur_path, filename=f'result_{idx}.svg',
                 attributes=[dict(fill="#000000", stroke="none", stroke_width=1)])

    path_list = [path_list[idx] for idx in (1, 3)]  # After analyzing the paths, we find that the paths index 1 and 3 seem to be redundant.
    single_path = CombinePath()  # combine: 0, 2 together.
    for combine_path in path_list:
        for curve in combine_path:
            single_path.append(curve)

    wsvg(single_path, filename=f'result.svg',
         attributes=[dict(fill="#000000", stroke="none", stroke_width=1)],
         openinbrowser=True  # default is False,
         )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

## result.svg

```html
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<svg baseProfile="full" height="600px" version="1.1" viewBox="-43.86259639916139 -43.9709554283007 601.8251942724853 601.9422429052738" width="600px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<defs/>
<path d="M 257.6,6.4 C 395.90000000000003,6.6000000000000005 508.1,119.5 507.6,258.0 C 507.1,395.7 394.3,507.9 256.5,507.6 C 118.3,507.2 6.0,394.1 6.5,255.8 C 7.0,117.9 119.5,6.2 257.6,6.4 M 256.6,358.8 C 256.90000000000003,363.0 257.20000000000005,366.40000000000003 257.3,369.7 C 257.5,397.3 257.6,425.0 257.7,452.6 C 257.7,467.70000000000005 253.5,471.5 238.6,470.20000000000005 C 127.0,461.0 41.4,366.1 42.9,253.3 C 44.3,141.9 133.4,49.1 244.6,43.0 C 347.0,37.4 439.4,104.7 464.5,203.4 C 490.0,303.1 441.8,406.0 348.6,450.5 C 344.90000000000003,452.3 340.8,453.4 337.6,455.9 C 335.70000000000005,457.4 333.8,461.4 334.5,463.29999999999995 C 335.2,465.09999999999997 339.5,466.99999999999994 341.7,466.49999999999994 C 346.3,465.59999999999997 350.7,463.29999999999995 355.0,461.29999999999995 C 454.0,414.0 504.5,302.0 474.9,195.8 C 445.3,90.0 344.1,21.3 234.1,32.3 C 103.7,45.4 11.8,166.1 34.1,295.2 C 51.8,397.9 133.3,472.6 238.6,483.0 C 243.5,483.5 248.6,486.2 252.79999999999998,489.0 C 260.0,493.9 267.0,494.7 273.29999999999995,488.8 C 279.69999999999993,482.8 279.19999999999993,475.90000000000003 274.49999999999994,468.5 C 271.99999999999994,464.5 269.79999999999995,459.4 269.69999999999993,454.8 C 268.99999999999994,425.5 269.0999999999999,396.1 268.3999999999999,366.8 C 268.19999999999993,358.6 270.7999999999999,354.3 278.3999999999999,350.5 C 304.2999999999999,337.5 317.8999999999999,310.4 314.2999999999999,281.7 C 310.6999999999999,253.7 290.4999999999999,230.79999999999998 262.8999999999999,224.5 C 255.99999999999991,222.9 248.69999999999993,222.7 241.5999999999999,222.0 C 211.89999999999992,218.9 191.0999999999999,194.6 192.39999999999992,164.3 C 193.49999999999991,136.60000000000002 216.99999999999991,113.60000000000001 245.0999999999999,112.9 C 274.4999999999999,112.10000000000001 298.7999999999999,133.5 301.4999999999999,162.60000000000002 C 301.7999999999999,166.20000000000002 302.1999999999999,169.90000000000003 302.5999999999999,174.60000000000002 C 315.7999999999999,174.60000000000002 327.9999999999999,174.40000000000003 340.2999999999999,174.60000000000002 C 381.4999999999999,175.3 417.5999999999999,206.00000000000003 423.5999999999999,245.60000000000002 C 430.0999999999999,287.90000000000003 406.5999999999999,327.40000000000003 366.9999999999999,341.20000000000005 C 360.7999999999999,343.40000000000003 355.5999999999999,344.90000000000003 349.5999999999999,338.70000000000005 C 342.7999999999999,331.70000000000005 330.9999999999999,334.1 325.19999999999993,341.80000000000007 C 319.49999999999994,349.30000000000007 320.5999999999999,359.6000000000001 327.69999999999993,365.80000000000007 C 334.79999999999995,371.9000000000001 344.79999999999995,371.00000000000006 351.99999999999994,364.9000000000001 C 356.8999999999999,360.80000000000007 362.49999999999994,356.80000000000007 368.49999999999994,354.9000000000001 C 409.29999999999995,341.80000000000007 437.9,303.7000000000001 438.19999999999993,261.0000000000001 C 438.49999999999994,218.80000000000013 411.0999999999999,179.40000000000012 370.5999999999999,167.0000000000001 C 356.8999999999999,162.80000000000013 341.7999999999999,162.30000000000013 327.19999999999993,161.80000000000013 C 318.19999999999993,161.5000000000001 314.5999999999999,159.40000000000012 312.29999999999995,150.10000000000014 C 302.9,112.90000000000013 264.49999999999994,91.80000000000014 227.59999999999997,102.60000000000014 C 191.59999999999997,113.20000000000013 170.99999999999997,151.70000000000013 182.19999999999996,187.90000000000015 C 191.09999999999997,216.90000000000015 214.69999999999996,233.70000000000016 249.89999999999998,235.90000000000015 C 273.4,237.40000000000015 292.4,252.20000000000016 299.2,274.20000000000016 C 306.0,296.10000000000014 298.59999999999997,319.90000000000015 280.4,333.8000000000002 C 277.4,336.1000000000002 273.79999999999995,337.8000000000002 269.09999999999997,340.6000000000002 C 268.79999999999995,334.9000000000002 268.49999999999994,331.2000000000002 268.29999999999995,327.6000000000002 C 266.59999999999997,300.50000000000017 247.19999999999996,277.3000000000002 220.89999999999995,271.4000000000002 C 213.89999999999995,269.9000000000002 206.59999999999994,270.0000000000002 199.59999999999994,268.8000000000002 C 178.19999999999993,265.4000000000002 161.29999999999995,255.1000000000002 150.39999999999992,235.90000000000018 C 147.19999999999993,230.2000000000002 146.69999999999993,225.50000000000017 151.79999999999993,219.40000000000018 C 155.19999999999993,215.40000000000018 156.29999999999993,206.80000000000018 154.29999999999993,201.90000000000018 C 152.59999999999994,197.60000000000016 144.99999999999991,192.90000000000018 140.29999999999993,193.10000000000016 C 134.99999999999991,193.30000000000015 129.69999999999993,198.50000000000017 124.99999999999993,202.30000000000015 C 121.29999999999993,205.30000000000015 118.99999999999993,210.40000000000015 114.99999999999993,212.80000000000015 C 87.49999999999993,229.60000000000016 71.89999999999992,260.90000000000015 76.49999999999993,290.8000000000002 C 82.89999999999993,331.6000000000002 114.29999999999993,358.8000000000002 155.89999999999992,359.00000000000017 C 189.1,359.0 222.2,358.8 256.6,358.8 M 198.8,345.6 C 183.5,345.6 168.10000000000002,345.90000000000003 152.8,345.5 C 123.4,344.7 98.10000000000001,324.2 91.10000000000001,296.0 C 84.30000000000001,268.5 96.9,238.5 121.0,224.6 C 129.6,219.7 133.1,220.9 136.2,230.0 C 146.29999999999998,259.1 172.0,278.8 202.89999999999998,280.3 C 220.09999999999997,281.1 234.99999999999997,286.2 245.99999999999997,300.0 C 254.29999999999998,310.4 256.79999999999995,322.5 257.2,335.4 C 257.5,342.5 254.6,345.29999999999995 247.79999999999998,345.29999999999995 C 231.39999999999998,345.19999999999993 215.09999999999997,345.29999999999995 198.7,345.29999999999995 C 198.8,345.4 198.8,345.5 198.8,345.6" fill="#000000" stroke="none" stroke-width="1"/>
</svg>
```