# Get a single path value for svg file having multiple paths

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg, designer

I am creating an icon component for which I am storing my icons as svg co-ordinates.

Eg:
trash: 'M192 1024h640l64-704h-768zM640 128v-128h-256v128h-320v192l64-64h768l64 64v-192h-320zM576 128h-128v-64h128v64z'

But certain svg icon files have multiple paths(like below). But I intend to have only one path value for storing my icon co -ordinates. Can someone please tell me what can I do to solve this?

```html
<svg id="add-contact-communication-workflow-system-filled" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
  <g id="Group_822" data-name="Group 822" transform="translate(-938.662 -1091.778)">
    <g id="Group_821" data-name="Group 821">
      <path id="Path_821" data-name="Path 821" d="M948.432,1103.947a4.063,4.063,0,1,0-4.063-4.062A4.067,4.067,0,0,0,948.432,1103.947Z"/>
      <path id="Path_822" data-name="Path 822" d="M948.432,1104.844a7.9,7.9,0,0,0-7.89,7.89,1.539,1.539,0,0,0,1.539,1.54h12.7a1.54,1.54,0,0,0,1.54-1.54A7.9,7.9,0,0,0,948.432,1104.844Z"/>
    </g>
    <path id="Path_823" data-name="Path 823" d="M960.033,1095.873h-1.84v-1.84a.75.75,0,0,0-1.5,0v1.84h-1.84a.75.75,0,0,0,0,1.5h1.84v1.84a.75.75,0,0,0,1.5,0v-1.84h1.84a.75.75,0,0,0,0-1.5Z"/>
  </g>
  <rect id="Rectangle_503" data-name="Rectangle 503" width="24" height="24" fill="none"/>
</svg>
```

here

Answer (score 0):

As long as the paths have the same style, and none of them have a `transform` different from the others, you can simply append the paths together into one.

```
M948.432,1103.947a4.063,4.063,0,1,0-4.063-4.062A4.067,4.067,0,0,0,948.432,1103.947Z M948.432,1104.844a7.9,7.9,0,0,0-7.89,7.89,1.539,1.539,0,0,0,1.539,1.54h12.7a1.54,1.54,0,0,0,1.54-1.54A7.9,7.9,0,0,0,948.432,1104.844Z M960.033,1095.873h-1.84v-1.84a.75.75,0,0,0-1.5,0v1.84h-1.84a.75.75,0,0,0,0,1.5h1.84v1.84a.75.75,0,0,0,1.5,0v-1.84h1.84a.75.75,0,0,0,0-1.5Z
```

Note that the three paths, in your example SVG, are inside a group that has a `transform`.  You may need to take account of that in your component if you want them to display in the correct place.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get rid of transforms and groups first. Then only it can be done. you can try the 'https://www.npmjs.com/package/svgo' module to optimize the svgs and convert them into a single path. But again you have to get rid of groups and transforms.